# Using LinqToExcel on a 64-bit build

Tags: asp.net

The page for [LinqToExcel](http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/) says it is required to compile the solution against x86.

How about, as I am using 64-bit Oracle, my application needs to be a 64-bit one.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Why do you think that connecting to a database running as a 64bit application means that _your_ application needs to be 64bit?

Comment: There is an exception thrown by dotConnect, the third party data provider we are using, when running as a 32-bit application and the solution is to compile as 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you do need it to be 64 bit as Oded says.  I think the problem with LinqToExcel might be related to the fact that there is no compatible 64bit OLEDB Jet driver.  MS did finally produce one for [Office 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c06b8369-60dd-4b64-a44b-84b371ede16d&displaylang=en) but it is likely you won't be able to just install it and get LinqToExcel to work.  Please note whilst is is called the Access Data Engine, it is used for programatic access to excel spreadsheets as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create A 64 Bit Service with wcf to handle the 64bit Oracle Calls.
Create a 32 bit program to handle the linq2Excel that then calls the WCF service to handle your data saves.